# How to repeat the first characters of every word in a sentence timed by three in python?

Tags: python, list, nested-loops

I want to make a function that takes a string (sentence) as an argument then takes the first word and saves every character that is a konsonant up to the first vowel (including the vowel) and save it in an empty string. Then i want it to take the second one and do the same thing... and so on... and so on...

Ex. input -> "This is good" output -> ThiThiThi iii gogogo

This is what i have came up with so far:

```
def lang(text): 
    alist=text.split() 
    kons="nrmg" nytext=" " 
        for word in alist: 
            for tkn in word: 
                if tkn in kons: 
                    nytext+=tkn 
                else: 
                    nytext+=tkn 
                    nytext=nytext*3 
                    nytext=nytext+"" break

    return nytext
print(lang("This is good"))
```

what i get is this -> T T Ti T T Ti T T Ti

What am i doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks :)

Comment: Why are the only "consonants" in your code lower-case n, r, m and g? Also, the code you've posted has several syntax errors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So the first thing is if you want to keep track of each word differently, then you need to use another variable(I called `retText`) because each word should be processed separately and results should be collected in the different variable.

Secondly, if you are looking for finding letters up to first vowel, then you need to check if the letter is vowel or not. `kons` variable holds the vowels and inside of the code, there is an

`if not tkn in kons:`

statement which checks if the tkn is vowel or not. Here is the full code:

```
def lang(text): 
    alist=text.split() 
    kons="aeiouAEIOU"
    retText="" 
    for word in alist: 
        nytext=""
        for tkn in word: 
            if not tkn in kons: 
                nytext+=tkn 
            else: 
                nytext+=tkn 
                retText += nytext*3 + " "
                break
        else:
            retText += word*3 + " " 
    return retText

print(lang("This is good"))
```

Comment: So what was wrong with the OP's code? What have you changed, and why?

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply! :) I don't understand the last else statement. Does that belong to the second for loop?

Comment: It blongs to the inner for loop. For-else is a control flow in Python. Check [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it. I am reading now :)

Comment: The code also seems to work if you take away the "...else: retText += word*3 + " "..." statement. Do i need that since it seems to be multiplying the variable word by 3, which it never does. What am i not getting?

Comment: It is needed in case of full of consonant word.